# yocto: how do I install header files along with kernel module in sdk

Tags: linux, yocto, kernel-module

Why, after do_install, test.h does not appear in SDK? Actually it appears nowhere.

```
do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}${includedir}/char-drv-ll
    install -m 0755 ${S}/test.h ${D}${includedir}/char-drv-ll/test.h
}
RPROVIDES_${PN} += "kernel-module-char-drv-ll"

FILES_${PN} += "${includedir}/char-drv-ll/test.h"
```

Edit: Here is the result of find in the poky build folder:

```sh
$ find -name test.h -and -path *char-drv-ll*
./tmp/sysroots-components/qemuarm/char-drv-ll/usr/include/char-drv-ll/test.h
./tmp/work/qemuarm-poky-linux-gnueabi/char-drv-ll/0.1-r0/package/usr/include/char-drv-ll/test.h
./tmp/work/qemuarm-poky-linux-gnueabi/char-drv-ll/0.1-r0/image/usr/include/char-drv-ll/test.h
./tmp/work/qemuarm-poky-linux-gnueabi/char-drv-ll/0.1-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/include/char-drv-ll/test.h
./tmp/work/qemuarm-poky-linux-gnueabi/char-drv-ll/0.1-r0/test.h
./tmp/work/qemuarm-poky-linux-gnueabi/char-drv-ll/0.1-r0/packages-split/char-drv-ll-dev/usr/include/char-drv-ll/test.h
```

The file `test.h` is nowhere to be found when I run qemu or in SDK, though.

Comment: Can you provide more details, is this recipe included in the image?

Comment: @md.jamal The recipe is included, and .ko file is properly installed. But any additional files, like test.h are not

Comment: Did you check the image folder inside tmp

Comment: @md.jamal I found it here:

./tmp/sysroots-components/qemuarm/char-drv-ll/usr/include/char-drv-ll/test.h
./tmp/work/qemuarm-poky-linux-gnueabi/char-drv-ll/0.1-r0/package/usr/include/char-drv-ll/test.h
./tmp/work/qemuarm-poky-linux-gnueabi/char-drv-ll/0.1-r0/image/usr/include/char-drv-ll/test.h
./tmp/work/qemuarm-poky-linux-gnueabi/char-drv-ll/0.1-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/include/char-drv-ll/test.h
./tmp/work/qemuarm-poky-linux-gnueabi/char-drv-ll/0.1-r0/test.h
./tmp/work/qemuarm-poky-linux-gnueabi/char-drv-ll/0.1-r0/packages-split/char-drv-ll-dev/usr/include/char-drv-ll/test.h

Answer (score 1):

By default packages are only included in the SDK if they are needed to build another package. E.g. if you are building an application its `DEPEND`s will be included in the SDK but not the application itself.

However you have the possibility to add packages explicitly to the SDK using the `TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK` and `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK` variables. (Remember that the SDK has a native and a cross-compile part)

Example:

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " nativesdk-mypackagename-dev"
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " mypackagename-dev"
```

If you have several packages you need to add, I would recommend you to group them in packagegroups (e.g. `nativesdk-packagegroup-mylayer-toolchain-host.bb`and `packagegroup-mylayer-toolchain-target.bb`)

Example `packagegroup-mylayer-toolchain-target.bb`:

```
DESCRIPTION= "Packages for the target part of the SDK"

inherit packagegroup

RDEPENDS_${PN} = ...the packages you want to add...
```

And then create a `classes/populate_sdk_mylayer.bbclass`:

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host nativesdk-packagegroup-mylayer-toolchain-host"
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " packagegroup-mylayer-toolchain-target"
```

Then you can bake it like `bitbake -c populate_sdk_mylayer myimage`