# Yocto: Is it possible to add header files in the target sysroot of the SDK but not to the target image itself

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I am creating a custom Yocto image for an embedded device. I wanted to know if it is possible to include header files in the SDK created with Yocto, but not to the image that will be installed on the target. I will never need the header files on my target, since I don't compile on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yocto does not include headers (or a toolchain) in the image by default. This needs to be explicitly specified, by adding `dev-pkgs` to `IMAGE_FEATURES` (refer to [Image Features](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/features.html#image-features) in the docs).

Header files and a cross-compile toolchain are included in the SDK by default (refer to [eSDK Introduction](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/sdk-manual/intro.html) in the docs).

If you need to add some headers to the SDK, you will need to write a recipe for them. Since that recipe is header-only, no files will end up in the target image - Yocto will split those files into a `-dev` package which will be added to any SDKs you generate for that image.

More detail on that is available in the following questions:

- [How to add header file to /usr/include in Yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517609/how-to-add-header-file-to-usr-include-in-yocto)
- [yocto: how do I install header files along with kernel module in sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780322/yocto-how-do-i-install-header-files-along-with-kernel-module-in-sdk)
- [Yocto Add own Header and Lib file's to sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67861043/yocto-add-own-header-and-lib-files-to-sdk)